# What is page name?

Tags: web, path, filenames

I often have a case, when I don't know real name of page. For example, if I go to stackoverflow.com, I don't know, do I go to stackoverflow.com/index.php or stackoverflow.com/index.html or some another page. And it can be none of index.*. Is a method to learn real full path and name of page?

Comment: The real full path is `https://stackoverflow.com/`.

Comment: I just toke example. And no, `https://stackoverflow.com/` is domain name and usually (especially, if we speak about Apache) domain name points to root directory of site and server automatically redirects client to file with page (`index.php`, for example). About that I speak — can I know the name of the finish file?

Comment: The concept of a direct correspondence between urls and disk files belongs to 1995.

Comment: Yes, about that I speak. Usually, URL gives file. And server gives a file, that's path is pointed in URL (relatively of root of site). If the URL points not to file, but to folder, server looks in that directory for file with especially name. Usually it is `index.php`, `index.html`, etc. I want to know, what exactly is this name in a current case.

Comment: Like I said, you cannot tell by looking at a URL whether or not there is a file one the disk, nor should you try. A URL that looks like `https://stackoverflow.com/files/archive.zip` may be processed by a controller at `https://stackoverflow.com/`, without having any files on disk. A URL that looks like `https://stackoverflow.com/index.php` can be processed by a controller at `https://stackoverflow.com` and make you think SO is written in PHP, which [it isn't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10369/147640).